# Create avy zap to char and up to char function

Tags: evil, avy

Good day,

I like the `zap to char` and `zap up to char` functions from evil. Since sometimes you would like to delete a prolonged sentence, I use `evil-delete` with selecting the char by `evil-avy-goto-char-in-line`.
I would like to assign a command to execute both commands with one key. However I am not technical enough to know how I should parse the argument to `evil-delete` to make this happen. So your help in creating this function would be greatly appreciated (or alternative suggestions how to zap long lines to a particular char).
A bonus would be if you could also provide the avy variant of go/zap up to char. I can't imagine how to make this happen without getting deeply involved in editing the avy code, which is obviously is not such a good idea.

Comment: Maybe consider `evilem-motion` package with `evilem-motion-find-char`, it can override the default Evil `f/F/t/T`.

Comment: Maybe check out `evil-snipe` package as well.

Comment: To my knowledge evil-snipe just jumps to the next to characters indicated. Also don't understand how this would contribute to have evil-delete and evil-avy-goto-char-in-line in one command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this. Note, the F8 key is just an example, I wouldn't use it.

```
(defun my/zap-to-char-avy ()
  "Delete region from point to a character."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (set-mark (point))
    (evil-avy-goto-char-in-line)
    (evil-delete (mark) (point) 'block)
    (deactivate-mark)))

(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<f8>") 'my/zap-to-char-avy)
```

Answer (score 0):

`evil-avy-goto-char-in-line` is an evil motion command, which means that you can combine it with `d, y, c` etc. You could bind it to `f` using `(evil-global-set-key 'motion "f" #'avy-goto-char-in-line)`, then you can use `df` for delete, `yf` for yank etc. (or choose any other available key).

But you might prefer to just use the default `f/F` keybinding, and then get used to repeat the jumps using `;`.